# Do the shards of Mjölnir have the same enchantment as Mjölnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok, mjolnir

Now that Mjölnir has been broken by Hela, do the shards still contain the enchantment placed on it?

For example, only someone who is worthy can pick up a shard of Mjölnir.

Comment: Given Thor's remark in the first film that magic and science are essentially the same thing for his people, it's likely the hammer needs to be whole for the enchantment/program to work.  The shards would still be pretty dense, but would not have the same strength as the solid thing.

Comment: The enchantment reads "Whosoever holds this _hammer_"..  it is no longer a hammer :)

Comment: Mjolnir is shown being destroyed in the first *Thor: Ragnarok* trailer. There was zero secrecy around that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Marvel Cinematic Universe: Unknown

The shards of Mjolnir as shown in *Thor: Ragnarok* have not been recovered or followed up on, either in theatrical films, short films, or tie-in comics.

## Marvel Comics: Yes

In Marvel Comics, Simon "Puddlegulp" Walterson (a man that a witch turned into a frog) recovered a sliver of Mjolnir and became…

***[Throg](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Throg), Frog of Thunder, and wielder of the mighty Frogjolnir!***

[image]
[image: The story of Throg, Frog of Thunder, and wielder of the mighty Frogjolnir]

<sub>Source: [*Lockjaw and the Pet Avengers* #1](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Lockjaw_and_the_Pet_Avengers_Vol_1_1)</sub>

> "His only *defense* was a small metal *sliver* chipped from Thor's hammer. […]
>
> "When he fell, the sliver *struck* the ground…and that that tiny frog was instantly transformed. […]
>
> "He had the power of the *god* of *thunder*, as well as his hammer.

As we can clearly see, the sliver of Mjolnir transforms into a miniature version of the larger hammer with the same enchantment and same inscription.

And the best part: **this is totally canon!** Throg crossed over into [Earth-616](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-616) (the mainstream Marvel Universe) in [*Thor* #700](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mighty_Thor_Vol_1_700) where a bunch of alternate-universe Thors teamed up.

Comment: Dear *gods*, but comics books are rad.

Comment: Lol. Thats even better than what I had in mind.  Was thinking that perhaps Thor could carry around a pocketful of shards and place one on top of anyone he wanted to pin to the ground (in the same way that he pinned Loki to the ground)

Comment: @JK. If Thor ever tried that, I expect that next time he summons Mjolnir he'll get a handful of enchanted splinters!

Comment: Wait, did Throg ever work with Spider-Ham?

Comment: @Forral Yes! In the animated TV series [*Ultimate Spider-Man* 3x10](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Spider-Man_(Animated_Series)_Season_3_10), Spider-Ham has a flashback from when he was part of the [Avengers](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers_(Earth-TRN456)) alongside Throg, Captain Americat, Iron Mouse, and Hulk Bunny.

Comment: Throg is now canon in MCU since he appeared in *Loki*.